# How to change font size in a WPF combobox for its popup only

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, combobox

In my WPF application I have a ComboBox. What I try to do is, to set a different font size on the popup only. The display of the selected item within the collapsed ComboBox should remain as it currently is.

Although I dismantled the whole thing to item templates and control templates in my XAML, I did not yet succeed to size only the popup's text...

Maybe one of you could give me the right point for doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change `ItemContainerStyle` for `ComboBoxItem`

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

this should affect only items in the popup

Comment: YES! That's the right spot. Works perfectly, thank you.